# About Twilio web hooks

Tags: c#, twilio, sms, webhooks, twilio-api

I have developed application, which is sending sms by twilio.
I need to track sms statuses - deliveries, fails, etc. for this reason I use twilio provided web hooks.

Of course I save sent sms into database - for some purposes and then also updating sms status in the db.
I achieved this by getting smsId - what twilio returns when sending sms - this id is saved into db - to track deliveries as mentioned above.

Actual question:
web hook is posting very fast to my endpoint status - actually for that time I event don't expect it to be saved in db.
I tried some of the optimizations - but nothing helped - still web hook is faster - so the resource is not in db - and of course I get NullReferenceException.

dealing with that - I came to the solution - to trying reading resource multiple times with some delays and at the end it gets resource and everything is fine.

actually - I don't like querying database multiple times for very small amount of time.

What can be other solution?

Code sample:

```
var response = _notificationSender.SendSms(new SendSmsRequest
{
      Text = text,
      ToNumber = contact.Mobile ?? contact.Phone
});

_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Table] ([field], .. ) Values(Field1,...),");
```

SendSms:

```
public SendSmsResponse SendSms(SendSmsRequest request)
{
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

   TwilioClient.Init(_twilioConfiguration.AccountSid, _twilioConfiguration.Token);

   var message = MessageResource.Create(
         body: request.Text,
         from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(FromNumber),
         statusCallback: new Uri(_twilioConfiguration.StatusCallbackUrl),
         to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(request.ToNumber)
   );

   return new SendSmsResponse
   {
         Ok = true,
         From = _twilioConfiguration.FromNumbers.First().Value,
         Sid = message.Sid,
         ErrorCode = (TwillioErrorCode?)message.ErrorCode,
         SmsStatus = response.SmsStatus
   };
}
```

Comment: Your question sounds very interesting, but, I  think it is difficult to answer you because there is not code to solve. I recommend you should read [how to create a minimal, reproducible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to see what kind of webhook you receive as soon as you call SendMessage API on Twilio. Twilio might send multiple webhooks based on the various status of the message at their end. And it might be sending the first webhook with the first status of the Message. So instead of relying on the API retunred messageID, you can completely depend on the WebHooks. And when you recieve first web hook you should store in the database and subsequent webhooks of the same message you should update.

Comment: We should do reporting by sms statuses - when app starts sending smses it also creates report instance and mapping to that sms - when sms is sent and got id, then it's inserted,
So, I can't rely on twilio web hooks, because if something goes wrong - I won't have information - I will not know if I sent it or why I received it.
there is one more problem also: when web hook posts - I don't know which reportid to assign

Comment: i dont see why you would get a null reference error

Comment: Read what I have written above, web hook calls before it gets inserted into db and of course i will get null reference when I try to get it from db, this is example code. Not the real one, but is very near

Comment: What would happen if you created the sms first and saved it inmediatly in the database before sending it, sequentially? So you ensure when the webhook arrives the sms will always be in the database

Comment: That can't be done, because the only identity, as I found out from documentation, is smsId, which is generated by twilio. So if I insert sms into db and web hook will post some Id, Still can't find resource with that id, because I don't have it in db.
I don't know, if inserting, then sending and updating db will be better choise.